# how to use jquery datetimepicker to show time in 30 min interval as checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, datetimepicker

i have a scenario in which i'm using jquery datetimepicker http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/ but i wanna do some customization for the UI. I don't want any dropdowns or sliders instead i wanna combine the hour:minute and show them as input checkboxes in order to let the user select which time they want to book.

I found the following option in the plugin:
controlType: myControl

but since i'm not that good at jquery/javascript therefore i couldn't figure out how to use hour and minute objects and combine them as hour:minute and show them as checkboxes. I would appreciate some direction or suggestions here.